# Haskell and lazy evaluation

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

Because of his lazyness can Haskell evaluate this next expression?

```
    take 3 (reverse [1..])
```

If so, can you try to explain me how?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you put it into GHCi and try it?

Comment: Why do you think that there is anything problematic about that line?

Comment: My guess is that you got the question wrong (is it `take 3 (reverse [1..])`?) - because this is obvious and has nothing to do with lazyness and I don't see what the explanation would be short of writing down the evaluation steps

Comment: @Carsten I think beginners have trouble understanding if an declared expression is actually evaluated or not. But i'm not sure if that's what Luxzero is having.

Comment: but in this cause should the question not be phrased "Because of lazyness **will** Haskell evaluate ..."?

Comment: Yeah I got the question wrong. Carsten was right

Comment: ok - assuming it was no *frustation edit* - the answer now is **no** - Haskell will not be able to evaluate this in an finite time - to see this ask yourself: what would the first element of the result of `reverse [1..]` be? (you can see this formally if you write down the definition of reverse and try to evaluate this by hand ... you soon will end up in some kind of mess ;))

Comment: Yeah that answers my question. Thanks for the help! And sorry about getting the question wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **no** - Haskell will not be able to evaluate this (on my system it will eat away tons of memory and crash at some point ;))

The reason is that you just cannot reverse an infinite list. To see this - assuming `reverse` is defined as:

```
reverse [] = []
reverse (x:xs) = reverse xs ++ [x]
```

you would now evaluate

```
reverse [1..]
= reverse 1:[2..]
{ 2nd case }
= reverse [2..] ++ [1]
= reverse (2:[3..]) ++ [1]
{ 2nd case }
= reverse [3..] ++ [2] ++ [1]
= ...
```

so you will always see yet another `reverse [n..]` with increasing `n` but never the case `reverse []`

So the evaluation will never end - and thus you will never be able to tell  what the first (or 2nd or 3rd) element will be

---

#### fun fact

Haskell has no problem evaluating

```
take 0 (reverse [1..])
```

though - and this time lazyness *wins the day* - can you see why?

Comment: Your fun fact turns out to be substantially more interesting than you may realize once you look at the *real* source code for `take`.

Comment: @dfeuer Can you explain? The [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#take) I found simply returns the empty list for `n<=0`.

Comment: @Eric, look just below `unsafeTake` to the `RULES`.

Comment: @Eric, even without the `RULES`, one is likely to be a bit surprised by the special case for `1` in `unsafeTake`.

Comment: @dfeuer :D ... to be honest I kindof expected the OP to take the naive implementation for take and just try to reason it out ^^

Comment: Another fun fact: If you precede the given code with `import Data.Int` and `default (Int16)`, the given expression returns immediately with `[32767,32766,32765]`, So keep in mind that `[1..]` is *not always an infinite list*. It may as well be finite.

Answer (score 0):

No, that will run forever, but it's *possible* to write a reverse function that produces the *spines* of lists lazily, and therefore gives

```
reverse' [1..] = repeat undefined
               = undefined : undefined : undefined : ...
```

instead of what the actual implementation gives,

```
reverse [1..] = undefined
```

Specifically

```
-- Take two lists and return the second with its
-- length fixed (perhaps truncated) to that of the
-- first. Blows up (eventually) if the second list
-- is shorter.
withLengthOf :: [a] -> [b] -> [b]
withLengthOf [] _ = []
withLengthOf (_ : xs) ~(y : ys) =
   y : withLengthOf xs ys

reverse' :: [a] -> [a]
reverse' xs = withLengthOf xs (reverse xs)
```

This is not generally the most useful thing (because lists have very boring spines) and it's somewhat inefficient. That's why the real `reverse` doesn't bother.

Comment: nice - still the question (can it be evaluated) would be no ;) (or so I think at 6am without my first coffee intake)